# AWS StepFunctions: Filter out empty objects in aggregate output

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with type `Map`. Is it possible to not have a value for an iteration in the aggregate output. If not, is there a way to filter out the empty objects in aggregate result? Or, would I need to do this in a lambda?

```
"Validate-All": {
  "Type": "Map",
  "ItemsPath": "$.shippedItems",
  "Parameters": {
    "item.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
  },
  "MaxConcurrency": 5,
  "Iterator": {
    "StartAt": "Validate",
    "States": {
      "Validate": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:process-input",
        "ResultPath": "$.output",
        "Next": "Is input validated successfully?",
      }, 
      "Is input validated successfully?": {
        "Type": "Choice",
        "Choices": [
          {
            "Variable": "$.output.isValidatedSuccessfully",
            "BooleanEquals": true
            "Next": "Validation Successful"
          },
        ],
        "Default": "Validation Failed"
      },
      "Validation Successful": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "OutputPath": "$.item" // -> outputs item
        "End": true
      },
      "Validation Failed": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Result": null, // -> outputs empty {}
        "End": true
      }
    }
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.ItemsProcessedSuccessfully", // aggregate outputs from map - contains empty {} that failed and item object that succeed
  "End": true
},
// Question: Is there a way to filter out empty {} in aggregate from map?
"CreateSuccessReport": {
    "Type": "Task",
    ...
    "End": true
}
```